# Unhandled promise rejection warning in React Native

Tags: react-native, exception, react-hooks, asynccallback

I'm getting the following warning while executing this function:

```
const requestCameraPermission = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('Requesting camera permission...')
    const permission = await CameraComponent.requestCameraPermission()
    console.log(`Camera permission status: ${permission}`)

    if (permission === 'denied') await Linking.openSettings()
    setCameraPermissionStatus(permission)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose your function with a try catch to handle a promise with async await.

```
const requestCameraPermission = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Requesting camera permission...')
    const permission = await CameraComponent.requestCameraPermission()
    console.log(`Camera permission status: ${permission}`)

    if (permission === 'denied') await Linking.openSettings()
    setCameraPermissionStatus(permission)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}, [])
```